# What settings are recorded in a VAO?

Tags: opengl, vao

In the following code sample, I set up a VAO where I try to bind the arguments of the vertex shader : the first argument are the vertices coordinates, the second one is the color, which is fixed and that I try to set up using glVertexAttrib3f. After setting up the VAO (setup ended by glBindVertexArray (0)), I call again glVertexAttrib3f, expecting that this will not affect the value that I have set up in the VAO.

The code compiles with :

```
$ g++ vao.cc -lglfw -lGLEW -lGL
```

Contents of vao.cc :

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include <iostream>

const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 600;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

GLuint compileShader (const char * VertexShaderCode, const char * FragmentShaderCode)
{
  int len;
  GLint res = GL_FALSE;
  GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader (GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
  GLuint FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader (GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);


  // Compile Vertex Shader
  glShaderSource (VertexShaderID, 1, &VertexShaderCode , NULL);
  glCompileShader (VertexShaderID);

  glGetShaderiv (VertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &res);
  glGetShaderiv (VertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len);
  if (len > 0)
    {
      char mess[len+1];
      glGetShaderInfoLog (VertexShaderID, len, NULL, &mess[0]);
      printf ("%s\n", mess);
    }


  // Compile Fragment Shader
  glShaderSource (FragmentShaderID, 1, &FragmentShaderCode , NULL);
  glCompileShader (FragmentShaderID);

  glGetShaderiv (FragmentShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &res);
  glGetShaderiv (FragmentShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len);
  if (len > 0)
    {
      char mess[len+1];
      glGetShaderInfoLog (FragmentShaderID, len, NULL, &mess[0]);
      printf ("%s\n", mess);
    }

  // Link the program
  GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram ();
  glAttachShader (ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
  glAttachShader (ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);
  glLinkProgram (ProgramID);
  
  // Check the program
  glGetProgramiv (ProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &res);
  glGetProgramiv (ProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len);
  if (len > 0)
    {
      char mess[len+1];
      glGetProgramInfoLog (ProgramID, len, NULL, &mess[0]);
      printf ("%s\n", mess);
    }
  
  
  glDetachShader (ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
  glDetachShader (ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);
  
  glDeleteShader (VertexShaderID);
  glDeleteShader (FragmentShaderID);
  
  return ProgramID;
}

int main ()
{
    glfwInit ();
    glfwWindowHint (GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint (GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint (GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow (SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "", NULL, NULL);

    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate ();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent (window);

    glewExperimental = true; 
    if (glewInit () != GLEW_OK)
      {
        fprintf (stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        glfwTerminate ();
        return -1;
      }

    glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    GLuint shader = compileShader 
(R"CODE(
#version 460 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aCol;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

out vec3 col;

void main ()
{
  gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4 (aPos, 1.0);
  col = aCol;
}
)CODE",
 R"CODE(
#version 460 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 col;

void main ()
{
    FragColor = vec4 (col, 1.0);
}
)CODE");

    glUseProgram (shader);

    float vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 
    };

    unsigned int VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays (1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers (1, &VBO);

    glBindVertexArray (VAO);

    glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof (vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer (0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof (float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray (0);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray (1);
    glVertexAttrib3f (1, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    glBindVertexArray (0);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray (1);
    glVertexAttrib3f (1, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    while (! glfwWindowShouldClose (window))
    {
        if (glfwGetKey (window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose (window, true);

        glClearColor (0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
        glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        
        glUseProgram (shader);

        glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective (glm::radians (20.0f), 1.0f / 1.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        glm::mat4 view       = glm::lookAt (glm::vec3 (6.0f,0.0f,0.0f), glm::vec3 (0,0,0), glm::vec3 (0,0,1));
        glUniformMatrix4fv (glGetUniformLocation (shader, "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, &projection[0][0]);
        glUniformMatrix4fv (glGetUniformLocation (shader, "view"), 1, GL_FALSE, &view[0][0]);

        glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        glUniformMatrix4fv (glGetUniformLocation (shader, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, &model[0][0]);

        glBindVertexArray (VAO);

        glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

        glfwSwapBuffers (window);
        glfwPollEvents ();
    }

    glDeleteVertexArrays (1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers (1, &VBO);

    glfwTerminate ();
    return 0;
}
```

So I expect a green square, but I get a red square, which implies that the color value I thought  was stored in the VAO has been replaced.

Questions :

- is it expected that values set by glVertexAttrib* are not stored in VAOs ?
- more generally, what is stored in VAOs, and what is not ?

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/99236/what-state-is-stored-in-an-opengl-vertex-array-object-vao-and-how-do-i-use-the

Answer (score 0):

As the name "Vertex *Array* Object" suggests, VAOs only [store the values pertient to vertex *arrays*](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object). The old [non-array way to specify attribute data](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Non-array_attribute_values) (which you should not be using) are global state, not part of VAOs.